# How to use Microsoft SEAL library for homomorphic encryption?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cryptography, seal

I want to use Microsoft SEAL library for homomorphic encryption in a university project. I have no prior experience on Visual Studio 2017 (15.9). After cloning [SEAL](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL) from github, I opened the solution file and tried to build the projects. But it shows about 1954 errors. The first errors are -

> E1696 cannot open source file "stddef.h"  SEALExamples    E:\Visual Studio Enterprise 2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\atomic   15
>
> E1696 cannot open source file "stdlib.h"  SEALExamples    E:\Visual Studio Enterprise 2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\atomic   17

There are many other errors like this for "errno.h", "float.h", "time.h" etc.
I think if I solved this errors, other errors will be gone. When I open an empty project, "stdlib.h" has no issue to be used.
So, am I doing something wrong? How can this be solved?

Comment: Try to update windows SDK to latest version and rebuild the project.

Comment: I have recently updated Visual Studio. Isn't latest windows SDK meant to be updated automatically when I updated Visual Studio?

Comment: for some reason I read "homophobic encryption"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it needed a specific version of windows SDK (10.0.16299). After installing it and selecting release mode instead of debug, everything worked.

Comment: The selecting release mode did it for me.